# Sound Waves Simulation in 3D Environment

Tags: algorithms, simulation, wave-propagation

I want to do a simulation of sound waves including wave propagation, absorption, and reflection in 3D space.

I did some research and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956331/wave-simulation-with-python) in stackoverflow but it talks about electromagnetic waves not sound waves.

I know I can reimplement the FDTD method for sound waves but how about the sources and does it act like electromagnetic waves? Are there any resources to start with?

Thanks in advance.